# Show post of different category in even odd position in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to show data in even or odd standard of different category in WordPress. for example one post of news type and another is second category.

**Code that I use for display**

```
$wp_query_array = null; 
$array1 = array('post_type' => array("post"),'posts_per_page' =>5);
$array2 = array('post_type' => array("news"),'posts_per_page' =>5); 
$posts = get_posts($array1); $news = get_posts($array2);

echo "<pre>";

foreach($posts as $key => $row){ 
  echo $posts[$key]->post_type;
  echo $news[$key]->post_type; echo "<br>"; 
}
```

You find this code here also:

http://laravel.io/bin/jQ8r9#7,15-16

Comment: please add what you try??

Comment: means list of post in WordPress of two different category and i have to show as

Comment: means list of post in WordPress of two different category and i have to show as at first first category post then second category post then again first category post and then second category as sequence will be proceed as.

Comment: are you try any code.

Comment: Yes `$wp_query_array = null;
  $array1 = array('post_type' => array("post"),'posts_per_page' =>5);
  $array2 = array('post_type' => array("news"),'posts_per_page' =>5);
  
  $posts = get_posts($array1);
  $news = get_posts($array2);
  echo "<pre>";
  foreach($posts as $key => $row){
   echo $posts[$key]->post_type;
   echo $news[$key]->post_type;
   echo "<br>";
  }`

Comment: you may visit this link: http://laravel.io/bin/jQ8r9#7,15-16

Answer (score 1):

Create a two objects of `wp_query` that iterate inside a main loop.When counter goes even it display post otherwise display news.

```
$post_data = array('post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page' =>5);
$news_data = array('post_type' => 'news','posts_per_page' =>5);


$post_arr = new WP_Query($post_data);
$news_arr = new WP_Query($news_data);

// counter variable

$postcount=0;

// get how many post in object

$total_post_count = ($post_arr->post_count)+($news_arr->post_count);

//Main while loop we can say container

while($postcount < $total_post_count) :

            if($postcount %2 == 0):

                        //This show post

                        while ( $post_arr->have_posts() ) : $post_arr->the_post();
                            echo '<li>';
                            $post_arr->the_title();
                            echo '</li>';
                        endwhile;

            else:
                        //This show news

                        while ( $news_arr->have_posts() ) : $news_arr->the_post();
                            echo '<li>';
                            $news_arr->the_title();
                            echo '</li>';
                        endwhile;
            endif;
endwhile;
```